# Proving that $f^{-1}$ is continuous

Tags: general-topology

We are given $f:X\to Y$ to be a bijective continuous function and my textbook has the following statement:

> We shall prove that images of closed sets of $X$ under $f$ are closed
>   in $Y$; this will prove continuity of the map $f^{-1}$.

I think the above statement is incorrect.

$f^{-1}:Y\to X$

The condition that $f^{-1}$ be continuous says that for each open set $U$ of $X$, the inverse image of $U$ under the map $f^{-1}$ is open in $Y$. But the *inverse image* of $U$ under the map $f^{-1}$ is the same as the *image* of $U$ under the map $f$. So, for $f^{-1}$ to be continuous, for each open set $U$ of $X$, $f(U)$ is open in $Y$. My textbook says "closed" instead of "open". Who is right?

Comment: You can try to prove that they're actually equivalent.

Comment: A map is continuous if and only if inverse images of open are open. Well, it turns out that this is equivalent to say that inverse images of closed are closed.

Comment: The answers explain that the following are equivalent here: i) $f^{-1}$ cont. ii) images of closed sets under $f$ are closed iii) images of open sets under $f$ are open iv) inverse im. of open sets under $f^{-1}$ are open v) inverse im. of closed sets under $f^{-1}$ are closed. But I want to point out that this does not generally hold (take a set with $\ge 2$ elements, let $X$ be that set with the discrete topology, $Y$ the same set with trivial topology, $f=$ identity. Then $f$ is cont. and bijective, but f^{-1} is not continuous.) The textbook's $f$ must have properties you have not stated.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that a function $f:X\to Y$ (where $X,Y$ are metric spaces) is continuous if and only if $f^{-1}(G)$ is closed in $X$ whenever $G$ is closed in $Y$.

In your case $f^{-1}:Y\to X$ is continuous if and only if $(f^{-1})^{-1}(G)=f(G)$ is closed in $Y$ whenever $G$ is closed in $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces and let $g: X\to Y$ be a function.

In general for $A\subseteq Y$ we have:$$g^{-1}(A^{\complement})=g^{-1}(A)^{\complement}$$

---

This makes it possible to prove that the following statements are equivalent:

$1)$ For every closed $F\subseteq Y$ the set $g^{-1}(F)\subseteq X$ is closed.

$2)$ For every open $U\subseteq Y$ the set $g^{-1}(U)\subseteq X$ is open.

$(1\implies2)$

Let $U\subseteq Y$ be open

Then $U^{\complement}$ is closed so that $g^{-1}(U)^{\complement}=g^{-1}(U^{\complement})$ is closed.

That means exactly that $g^{-1}(U)$ is open.

$(2\implies1)$

Let $F\subseteq Y$ be closed.

Then $F^{\complement}$ is open so that $g^{-1}(F)^{\complement}=g^{-1}(F^{\complement})$ is open.

That means exactly that $g^{-1}(F)$ is closed.

---

So you and your textbook are saying equivalent things.